# Issue with fetching data from mysql according to recent timestamp ASC ordering

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am having trouble with mysql query to fetch the data according to the recent timestamp in ASC order. it means the recent updated one record will be first shown. The Query is grouping with the employee names.

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE b.grade_marks,b.comment,b.date,b.employee_name,b.employee_image,b.grade_id,GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN b.day = 'Monday' 
                   THEN b.grade_marks ELSE NULL END) AS Monday
,GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN b.day = 'Tuesday' 
                   THEN b.grade_marks ELSE NULL END) AS Tuesday
,GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN b.day = 'Wednesday' 
                   THEN b.grade_marks ELSE NULL END) AS Wednesday
,GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN b.day = 'Thursday' 
                   THEN b.grade_marks ELSE NULL END) AS Thursday
,GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN b.day = 'Friday' 
                   THEN b.grade_marks ELSE NULL END) AS Friday
,GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN b.day = 'Saturday' 
                   THEN b.grade_marks ELSE NULL END) AS Saturday
,GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN b.day = 'Sunday' THEN b.grade_marks ELSE NULL END) AS Sunday,SUM(b.grade_marks) As Total FROM grade b inner join (SELECT grade_marks,comment,date,employee_name,employee_image,grade_id, MAX(date) FROM grade group by grade_id) as a on a.grade_id=b.grade_id WHERE  YEARWEEK(`grade_date`, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1) and b.disable=0 GROUP BY b.employee_name ORDER BY Total DESC,(SELECT MAX(date) FROM grade) ASC
```

The date Field is used as timestamp. But the result getting from the above query shuffle the date everytime. I want to get the data according to the recent timestamp updated.?

For example: i have employee with name darcy, lillly. They both have 4,4 marks. Darcy updated at 2016-02-12 01:01:50 with marks 4 and lilly updated at updated at 2016-02-12 02:01:50 with marks 4. So according to the query the darcy will be come before lilly. but unfortunately the query shuffles the positioning. :(

I want that if the total value are same of anyone of employee, the employee with timestamp last updated will be show before the recently updated one.??

Comment: `ORDER BY (SELECT MAX(date) FROM grade) ASC, Total DESC`?

Comment: its because i want to get data according to the maximum total and with date in ASC order. The higher total employee will come before.

Comment: So when you say shuffle, you get `5, 2/12/16 - 5, 1/12/16` instead of `5, 1/2/16 - 5, 2/12/16`?

Comment: For example: i have employee with name darcy, lillly. They both have 4,4 marks. Darcy updated at 2016-02-12 01:01:50 with marks 4 and lilly updated at updated at 2016-02-12 02:01:50 with marks 4. So according to the query the darcy will be come before lilly. but unfortunately the query shuffles the positioning. :(

Comment: Edit your question to include the result you get vs. what you want.

Comment: i have edited my question artm. thnx .

Comment: If you want the latest timestamp to come first, don't you need DESC?

Comment: artm i had trie DESC too. but it same shuffling the timestamp. i am stuck on it.:(

Comment: artm can you help me.?